# Configuration Manager AppSettings

Tags: vb.net, configuration, app-config

I have a vb.net windows application(converse) which is internally connected with other applications. This application converse.dll is called by others application but my problem is the app.config file of this application is not been accessed by the application.

```html
ConfigurationManager.Appsettings("Key_value")
```

is not working and not getting values from converse.dll.config. What can be the possibilities that the config files is not accessed? Since it is a previously made application and linked with other applications so is it possible that the config file of this application is replaced?

Comment: You are supposed to add the configuration required by your DLL to the application's config file.

Comment: Its already added <configuration>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="Setting1" value="Value1" />
    <add key="Setting2" value="Value2" />
 </appSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: conversion.dll.config will never be used.  It only ever reads appname.exe.config, where appname is the name of the EXE project that uses converse.dll.  That makes using application settings in a library project less than ideal.  Consider that an EXE project can set public properties exposed by a library class.